# Acton in for loop not affecting all sprites in a group

Tags: python, pygame

Attempting to make a space invaders style game, and I want to affect all enemies using a for loop - but with the code shown I get a logical error where only the 1st enemy is affected, and only the first enemy can access/use the enemy.moveLR() method within the enemy class. The method of the class is not highlighted as yellow, nor does VS Code's intellisense pick it up.

Code concerning the enemy:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,path):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.xChange = 0
        self.hp = 0
    
    def moveLR(self):

        if self.rect.x >= 750 and self.xChange > 0:

            self.xChange = -5
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y +30
        
        if self.rect.x <= 0 and self.xChange < 0:

            self.xChange = 5
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y +30
```

And my main loop, including the code that isn't working:
(The final for loop)

```
while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                bullet = Bullet('bullet.png')
                allActiveSpritesList.add(bullet)
                bulletList.add(bullet)
                bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 45
                bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_a:

                    player.goLeft()
                
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:

                    player.goRight()
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key == pygame.K_a or pygame.K_d:

                    player.stop()

        player.rect.x += player.changeX
        player.rect.y += player.changeY
        
        enemy.rect.x += enemy.xChange

        timer = timer + 1
            
        for enemy in enemyList:
            
            enemy.moveLR()
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move all the enemies in `enemyList.` Move the `enemy` in the loop:

```py
# enemy.rect.x += enemy.xChange           <-- DELETE

timer = timer + 1

for enemy in enemyList:
    enemy.rect.x += enemy.xChange       # <-- INSERT
    enemy.moveLR()
```

I suggest to do all the movement in the `moveLR` method:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def moveLR(self):

        self.rect.x += self.xChange     # <---

        if self.rect.x >= 750 and self.xChange > 0:

            self.xChange = -5
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y +30
        
        if self.rect.x <= 0 and self.xChange < 0:

            self.xChange = 5
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y +30
```

```py
for enemy in enemyList:
    enemy.moveLR()
```